# Why doesn't SaltStack pkg.installed command recognize installed packages on CentOS 6.6

Tags: git, centos6, salt-stack, java

I have a series of formulas that worked fine on Ubuntu, but I'm finding that they don't work correctly on my minion running CentOS release 6.6 (Final). The minion is running salt version: salt-minion 2014.7.0 (Helium)

For example, the git-core package is not working:

```
git-core:
    pkg.installed
```

When I run highstate, I get this error:

```
[user] out: ----------
[user] out: ID: git-core
[user] out: Function: pkg.installed
[user] out: Result: False
[user] out: Comment: Package 'git-core' not found (possible matches: git, wt-git)
[user] out: Changes:   
[user] out: ----------
```

When I attempt to manually install the requirements on the server, they appear to be already installed:

```
root@host [225 01:41:35 /home/project]# yum install git-core
Loaded plugins: changelog, downloadonly, fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
Package wt-git-1.7.1-1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Why does git-core appear to be 'not found' by SaltStack, when it's installed?

BTW, there is a whole set of errors across packages, not just git, including:

```
[user] out: ----------
[user] out:           ID: ssh
[user] out:     Function: service.running
[user] out:       Result: False
[user] out:      Comment: The named service ssh is not available
[user] out:      Changes:   
[user] out: ----------
[user] out:           ID: iptables-persistent
[user] out:     Function: pkg.installed
[user] out:       Result: False
[user] out:      Comment: The following package(s) were not found, and no possible matches were found in the package db: iptables-persistent
[user] out:      Changes:   
[user] out: ----------
[user] out:           ID: iptables-persistent
[user] out:     Function: service.running
[user] out:       Result: False
[user] out:      Comment: The named service iptables-persistent is not available
[user] out:      Changes:   
[user] out: ----------
[user] out:           ID: openjdk-6-jdk
[user] out:     Function: pkg.installed
[user] out:       Result: False
[user] out:      Comment: The following package(s) were not found, and no possible matches were found in the package db: openjdk-6-jdk
[user] out:      Changes:   
[user] out: ----------
[user] out:           ID: tomcat6
[user] out:     Function: pkg.installed
[user] out:       Result: False
[user] out:      Comment: The following packages failed to install/update: tomcat6.
[user] out:      Changes:   
[user] out: ----------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you've already found this, but for the sake of the next person, it's `sshd` on my CentOS boxes. Try something like:

```
{% if grains['os_family']=="RedHat" %}

sshd:
    service.running

{% elif grains['os_family']=="Debian" %}

ssh:
    service.running

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is because packages may have slightly different names depending on the os family.

To workaround, I updated the git package name for "RedHat" systems to 'wt-git':

```
{% if grains['os_family']=="RedHat" %}
wt-git:
    pkg.installed
{% elif grains['os_family']=="Debian" %}
git-core:
    pkg.installed
{% endif %}
```

and for java:

```
{% if grains['os_family']=="RedHat" %}

java-1.6.0-openjdk:
    pkg.installed

{% elif grains['os_family']=="Debian" %}

openjdk-6-jdk:
    pkg.installed

{% endif %}
```

Still not sure what the workaround is for the SSH service.running not being recognized.